# Javascript clearInterval with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, clearinterval

I'm having issues getting clearInterval to work when I try to bind it to a button click. Also, apparently the function is starting on it's own... Here's my code

```
var funky = setInterval(function() {
    alert('hello world');
}, 2000);

$('#start').click(function() {
    funky();
});
$('#stop').click(function() {
    clearInterval(funky);
});
```

[Here's a js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40k11jjb/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have forgot to add `jquery` library and have made wrong assignment, it needs to be inside callback function.

Working example:

```js
var funky;

$('#start').click(function() {
  funky = setInterval(function() {
    alert('hello world');
  }, 2000);
});

$('#stop').click(function() {
    clearInterval(funky);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, yes, when you assign a variable to a function, it self invokes.

Secondly, your click events are not working because you need assign the interval to the variable on the click, not invoke the function - there is no function to invoke, as you would see if you looked at your developer console.

Lastly, it is good practice to wrap the jQuery code in the document ready function to ensure all of your event handlers get bound properly.

```
$(function () {
  var funky;
  $('#start').click(function() {
    funky = setInterval(function() {
      alert('hello world');
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('#stop').click(function() {
      clearInterval(funky);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saving the wrong value. Try this:

```
var funky = function() {
    alert('hello world');
}

var funkyId = setInterval(funky, 2000);

$('#start').click(function() {
    funky();
});
$('#stop').click(function() {
    clearInterval(funkyId);
});
```

Comment: I dont think he wants to start the interval until start button is clicked

Comment: @Rosenumber14 - my mind reading skills are far inferior to my programming skills. perhaps OP should read [ask] and ask better questions.

Comment: "Also, apparently the function is starting on it's own..." <- this was part of his question, and looking at his code you can tell he wants to start the interval when the button named "start" is clicked and stop the interval when "stop" is clicked. Seems to be the scenario that makes the most sense...

Answer (score 0):

Here I am giving you the idea.

1. declare a variable e.g. `let x;`
2. create a function which you want to bind with `setInterval`.
   e.g. 
   `function funky() {
   alert("Hello World");
   }`
3. assign `start.onclick` to a function which will assign the `setInterval` to `x`.
   e.g `start.onclick = function(){
   clearInterval(x); // to prevent multiple interval if you click more than one
   x = setInterval(funky, 2000); // assign the setInterval to x
   };`
4. assign `stop.onclick` to `clearInterval(x)` to stop the interval.
   e.g. `stop.onclick = function() {
   clearInterval(x); // to stop the interval
   };`

That's it. Easy right.