# How can I set timers in slideshow to show as selected?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, timer, slideshow

I have to create a slideshow, using an array of images and have that set on a timer. There is a drop-down menu with slow, medium, and fast options and the pictures need to transition with accordance to the drop down option selected. Whenever I execute this code in a web browser the code repeats itself, while doubling, as I read the value of *i* in the console.

I have tried using a while and a do-while loop to have the images on a rotation.

I have also tried putting the if-statements outside and below/above the function.

```
<script>
var i = 0;
function changeImg(){
    if (x == 'slow'){
        setInterval("changeImg()", 5000);
    } else if (x == 'medium'){
        setInterval("changeImg()", 3000);
    } else if (x == 'fast') {
        setInterval("changeImg()", 1000);
    } else {}

        while (i < 3){
            console.log(i);
            document.slide.src = sportsArray[i];
            i++;
        }

        console.log(i);
        console.log(sportsArray);
    }
</sctipt>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would read up on MDN's docs on [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) to fill in the knowledge gaps that lead you to approach the problem this way.

You are recursively calling `changeImg()` in your code which I believe is causing the issue you describe as:

> the code repeats itself, while doubling, as I read the value of i in the console

Also, your while loop will run immediately when calling `changeImg()` which also does not appear to be desired in this situation.

`setInterval()` mimics a while loop by nature. There is no need for a while loop in this code. Below is a solution that I hope you can use as a reference. I separated the code to determine the interval into a function the `getIntervalSpeed`.

```
function changeImg(x) {
    var getIntervalSpeed = function(x) {
        if (x === 'slow') {
            return 5000;
        } else if (x === 'medium') {
            return 3000;
        } else if (x === 'fast') {
            return 1000;
        } else {
            return 3000;
            // return a default interval if x is not defined
        }
    };

    var i = 0;

    var slideShow = setInterval(function() {
        if (i >= sportsArray.length) {
            i = 0; // reset index
        }

        document.slide.src = sportsArray[i]; // set the slide.src to the current index
        i++; // increment index
    }, getIntervalSpeed(x));

    // on click of ANY button on the page, stop the slideshow
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        clearInterval(slideShow);
    });

}
```

Comment: This is a huge help, thank you! One more question though - How can I set the *clearInterval(slideShow)* to a button. Also how would I make the function so that the loop is infinite, as in restarting back to array[0] after *i* reaching 3?

Comment: As for binding clearInterval(slideShow) to a button click event, I'd check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543966/setinterval-and-clearinterval-through-button-click-events) to get some ideas. As for making the loop infinite, you'll only need to change one line of code from my answer above. Think about it. If `i >= 3`, then you should set `i` to what?

Comment: You could also checkout [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36022170/11287029) to call clearInterval() on a click event

Comment: set `i = sportsArray.length`? I have no clue what I would set it to. I have also made a function `function stopPics(){ clearInterval(slideShow); }` although I cannot get that to work... (The console says *slideShow* is undefined.)

Comment: I've updated my solution above to reflect what you need. You need to reset `i = 0`. I added logic that on click of any button element on the page, will stop the slide show, you need to change the `querySelector` function to select your specific button. `slideShow` needs to be defined in the calling scope, that's why you're getting undefined.